# Phonegap Android Splash Screen not working

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I am building and Application using Phonegap. Following is my problem:

I did cordova create hello, then I did cordova platform add android , followed by cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen and then finally cordova build android.

My top level config.xml contains:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" ></preference> 
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

My index.html from www folder contains

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

My main.js somewhere contains:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

I imported

```
<project root directory>/platforms/android into eclipse ADT.
```

I guess navigator.splashscreen.hide() is not working because splashscreen gets hide on 3000 ms only, which is by default and I am getting this on my ADT Logcat:

```
06-10 12:33:39.641: W/System.err(7663): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen
```

and a large dump regarding the same and then

```
06-10 12:33:39.651: D/PluginManager(7663): exec() call to unknown plugin: SplashScreen
```

Comment: Does your android project contains "SplashScreen.java" class?

Comment: No, after adding cordova plugin I have this directory structure :        <Root Directory of Project>/assets/plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js

Comment: You should also get structure as : Project -> Platforms-> Android ->src->org->apache->cordova->splashscreen-> Splashscreen.java